# How to join two collections using rxjs?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs

I have two collections (tokens and trends) that have to be joined by id such that every returned item is composed by the document from tokens and trends collection (the id of the trends item is equal to the id of the tokens item).

In order to merge the documents, I have created the following function:

```
export interface TokenData {
    created_utc: number;
    image: string;
    name: string;
}

export interface usersCount {
    subscribers: number;
    visitors: number;
    timestamp: number;
}

export interface TrendData {
    tokenInfo: TokenData;
    users_count: usersCount[];
}

getTrends(): Observable<TrendData[]> {
      const tokens = this.db.collection<TrendData>('tokens').snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(map(docArray => {
        return docArray.map(doc => {
          const data: any = doc.payload.doc.data();
          return {
            id: doc.payload.doc.id,
            ...data
          };
        });
      }));
      const trends = this.db.collection<TrendData>('trends').snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(map(docArray => {
        return docArray.map(doc => {
          const data: any = doc.payload.doc.data();
          return {
            id: doc.payload.doc.id,
            ...data
          };
        });
      }));
      const fj = forkJoin({
        tokens: tokens,
        trends: trends
      });
      return fj.pipe(map(items => {
        return items.trends.map(trendItem => {
          return {
            tokenInfo: items.tokens.find(({id}) => id === trendItem.id),
            users_count: trendItem
          }
        })
      }))
    }
```

In general, I would like to join two firestore collections but the current function doesn't return anything so I am not sure if forkJoin is the right operator or is there any other issue that prevents the subscribed function to retrieve the data.

Comment: `fj.pipe(` is missing the closing `)`. It's not so much that a comma is missing, but that the parser encounters a `}` where it would otherwise expect a `,` or a `)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using combineLatest instead of forkJoin, I made it working:

```
getTrends(): Observable<TrendData[]> {
      const tokens = this.db.collection<TrendData>('tokens').snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(map(docArray => {
        return docArray.map(doc => {
          const data: any = doc.payload.doc.data();
          return {
            id: doc.payload.doc.id,
            ...data
          };
        });
      }));
      const trends = this.db.collection<TrendData>('trends').snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(map(docArray => {
        return docArray.map(doc => {
          const data: any = doc.payload.doc.data();
          return {
            id: doc.payload.doc.id,
            ...data
          };
        });
      }));
      const merged = combineLatest([tokens, trends]).pipe(
        map(([tokens, trends]) => {
          return trends.map(trendItem => {
            return {
              tokenInfo: tokens.find(({id}) => id === trendItem.id),
              users_count: trendItem
            }
          })
        })
        )
      return merged;
    }
```